# 2 блока в карусели bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Как настроить чтобы в контейнере карусели было сразу 2 колонки? при нажатии стрелки последняя с краю уходит и заходит другая колонка. В owlcarousel это можно легко сделать а в бутстрапе есть такая возможность?

```css
.block
 height: 200px
 border: 1px solid black  

.poss
 position: absolute
 top: 50%
 transform: translateY(-50%)

.carousel-indicators li
 background: gray 
 
.carousel-indicators li.active,.carousel-indicators li
 width: 33px
 height: 33px 
 border-radius: 50%
 text-indent: 0
 border: none
 color: black
 padding-top: 3px 
 margin: 1px
 
.carousel-indicators li:hover
 background: green 
.carousel-indicators li.active
 background: green
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-css/1.4.6/select2-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div id="testCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="0">
  <!-- Индикаторы карусели -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#testCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">1</li>
   <li data-target="#testCarousel" data-slide-to="1">2</li>
   <li data-target="#testCarousel" data-slide-to="2">3</li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Слайды карусели -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <!-- Слайд 1 -->
   <div class="item active">
    <div class="block"><p>Это блок 1</p></div>
   </div>
   <!-- Слайд 2 -->
   <div class="item ">
    <div class="block"><p>Это блок 2</p></div>
   </div>
   <!-- Слайд 3 -->
   <div class="item">
    <div class="block"><p>Это блок 3</p></div>
   </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Навигация карусели (следующий или предыдущий слайд) -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#testCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-left poss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#testCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <i class="fa fa-chevron-right poss" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В бутстрапе карусель слишком уныла. Я всегда использую в нем slick slider

Comment: @РашенБеар Ну да slick slider многообразна, просто думал чтобы лишние плагины не подключать, можно сразу каруселькой бутстрапа пользоваться и настраивать её как угодно. В общем понятно что в контейнере слайдера может быть только один блок

Comment: так карусель бутстрапа - это тоже лишний  плагин.Особой разницы нет. Убираем при компиляции из бутстрапа карусель и подключаем свою